# Weak convergence + compactness = strong convergence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $K$ a compact subset of $X$. If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence such that $x_n\in K$ for all $n$  and $(x_n)_n$ converges weakly to some $x\in X$, i.e. $x^*(x_n)\to x^*(x)$ for all $x^*\in X^*$ the dual space of $X$.

I know that we have the strong convergence for some subsequence. But, do we have the strong convergence of the whole sequence?

Comment: A compact space does not a have a strictly weaker Hausdorff topology.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ has the following property:

"Every subsequence has a subsequence which converges to $x$."
It follows that the whole sequence must converge to $x$. For more details see the questions:

[Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-then)

[Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451764/proving-that-the-mothersequence-converges-to-x-if-any-subsequence-contains-a-s)

[Question 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque)